# Understanding how any function definition in scala evaluates to a trait

Tags: scala, function, traits

I am currently looking into a couple scala code bases (each was maintained by different set of people across different geographical locations) and I feel that Scala offers different ways to do the same thing. My first hand understanding has been that Scala has a pretty thick layer of syntactic sugar code, so my immediate goal now is to penetrate that layer and see what are the fundamental building blocks.

As I understand after reading some docs, every function definition in scala is basically a trait with a filled "apply" method.(analogous to interface with anonymous body/class in java). Setting this as the basis (please correct me if my base understanding itself is wrong), I am playing around with function definitions in Scala.

Consider this:

```
  def func (s:String):Int = {
    100
  }
```

evaluates to

```
  new Function1[String, Int] {
    def apply(s:String):Int = {
      100
    }
  }
```

But what(and how) does the following evaluate to a trait definition?

```
 def func (body: => Boolean):Int = {
    body;
    100;
 }
```

What the "new Function ... " code look like in this case?

Answer (score 3):

In case of confusion, look in `javap` output. Scala's REPL gives convenient way to check it:

```
scala>  def func (body: => Boolean):Int = {
     |     body;
     |     100;
     |  }
func: (body: => Boolean)Int

scala> :javap -c func
Compiled from "<console>"
public class  {
  public static final  MODULE$;

  public static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class 
       3: invokespecial #12                 // Method "<init>":()V
       6: return

  public int func(scala.Function0<java.lang.Object>);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: invokeinterface #20,  1           // InterfaceMethod scala/Function0.apply$mcZ$sp:()Z
       6: pop
       7: bipush        100
       9: ireturn

  public ();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #24                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: putstatic     #26                 // Field MODULE$:L;
       8: return
}
```

So here you can see that `body: => Boolean` is represented as `scala.Function0<java.lang.Object>` in bytecode.

I'm using `scala 2.11.8` version here. `Scala 2.12` will try to reuse java8's features like default methods (in interfaces) or SAMs as much as possible (you can try `-Xexperimental` flag, that enables introp for `2.11`). That will lead to another bytecode (incompatible with java < 8) and better performance. You can read more about `2.12` changes [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12-roadmap).

Comment: Thanks dveim! That was insightful. So how would the "new Function ..... "   code look like for it?

Comment: @soupybionics Something like ```val body = new Function0[Boolean] { def apply(): Boolean = println("calling body"); true }```, and similar `Function1` for `func`. Note that `: =>` syntax (also called call-by-name) is nothing more but a `function that takes 0 args and returns something`.

Comment: Looking at byte code doesn't really explain what happens with types. You can't define it with `Function0`, it will have a different type.

Comment: @dveim Nope, types are different. Function that takes 0 args and returns something will be `() => Something`, and you will have to call it differently, with parentheses.

Comment: @VictorMoroz I mean there is no difference between `x : => Something` and `x: () => Something`. Indeed, except parentheses, they cannot be applied to `: =>` and (to force evaluation) must be applied to `() => Something`. You can verify that with `javap -c`: http://pastebin.com/g7gub10p .

Comment: @dveim True, there is no difference in JVM bytecode, but it doesn't mean types are the same, try this: `val f: (=> Boolean) => Int = (b: () => Boolean) => 1`. Also there are other platforms beyond JVM, you have no guarantee it will happen there too. What happens in JVM is only interesting when you interact with e.g. Java.

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
def func (s:String):Int = {
  100
}
```

is not a function, it's a method, it has no value and doesn't *evaluate* to anything by itself. When placed in a functional context it does expand to a function, but to a different one (Scala creates a wrapper):

```
new Function1[String, Int] {
  def apply(s:String):Int = {
    func(s)
  }
}
```

So if you want to eta-expand (Scala's term for converting a method to a function)

```
def func (body: => Boolean):Int = {
  body;
  100;
}
```

it should be something like:

```
new Function1[=> Boolean, Int] {
  def apply(body: => Boolean):Int = {
    func(body)
  }
}
```

and Scala shows type as:

```
(=> Boolean) => Int
```

but the problem here is that by-name types can't be used as type parameters, so it looks like there is no legal way to define this function using `Function1` trait.

**UPDATE**

Looks like there is a workaround by using lambda syntax (I can't declare the type of `body` explicitly though, by-name is not allowed there):

```
var expandedFunc: (=> Boolean) => Int = body => func(body)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Dviem's comments, the code should look something like this:

```
val func = new Function1[()=>Boolean, Int] {
             def apply(fn:()=>Boolean):Int = { fn(); 100 }
           }

>>> func: (() => Boolean) => Int = <function1>

func (new Function0[Boolean] {
        def apply():Boolean  = { println ("returning true"); true }
      })

>>> returning true
>>> res0: Int = 100
```